# how to aggregate a match and a sample with mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can aggregate a sampling operation, but it doesn't seem to work with a match:

```
 self.db.dataset.aggregate([
                { "$match": { country: country } },
                { "$sample": {"size": 1}}
            ])
```

Which when used on its own works fine:

```
self.db.dataset.aggregate([{"$sample": {"size": 1}}])
```

The problem with the first approach is that the operation returns a cursor, but it has nothing in it.

Is that even possible?

Comment: It has there https://mongoplayground.net/p/pciuSxRr9t9. Does your "$match" match any documents at all?

Comment: so like: { "$match": { country: Germany } }   i.e. all by itself returns nothing?

Comment: @AlexBlex No, I'm an idiot, that was the problem. Fixed the `match` and sample seems to work now.